# Horizontal gallery responsive jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, gallery

I would like to make a horizontal gallery responsive like this site:

http://www.worldofthreea.com/evenfall001/fq890fu24ipgm09rgdjc5bitgnluuv

with css3 or jquery

Does anyone know if there is a plugin to do this?

Tnx a lot

Comment: Bootstrap, foundation zurb or skeleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a responsive slider, not exactlly a gallery i would say, if you want a gallery check one of those plugins http://jster.net/category/layout , masonry, isotope or packery can get you some nice gallery like feel while being responsive, if you only want an image slider without haveing to implement UI framework i.e foundation, bootstrap which have this feature buit-in try some custom slider like nivo slider or check this site for tones of options http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/

gl m8 :)